# Errors related to zoo package and dates

Tags: r, zoo, hydrotsm

I started getting an error with a data and code that was working fine and now does not. The work is regarding rainfall data and the [hydroTSM package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hydroTSM/vignettes/hydroTSM_Vignette-knitr.pdf) which requires zoo. When I get to a part in the code, a simple function included in the hydroTSM package wont run. After troubleshooting, I think it's related to the zoo package but am not 100% sure.

I tried to clean my data using trimws() and use multiple ways to convert my df to a zoo, but nothing. I've started a new R session and rebooted my machine. I also reinstalled HydroTSM. Any idea what it is?

**Data**

EXAMPLE

```
Date, Rainfall
2001-01-01  0.00
2001-01-02  0.00
2001-01-03  0.00
2001-01-04  0.00
2001-01-05  0.00
2001-01-06  0.00
2001-01-07  0.00
```

[LINK TO FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndfv5wjxbma9g2e/Rainfall2?dl=0)

**Code**

```
## Library Packages
library(hydroTSM)
library(devtools)

## Read in the data and format for zoo
df <- read.table("Rainfall2" , header = TRUE, sep="\t")
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date , format = "%m/%d/%y")
x <- zoo(df[, -1], df[, 1])
dates <- time(x)

## Run the daily2monthly function in HydroTSM
m <- daily2monthly(x, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

> Error in daily2monthly(x, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE) :    unused arguments (FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)

If you look at the link to the package, I am following the directions almost exactly except how I format my data, which I came up with on my own. So I also tried the following code to convert to zoo and got this error.

```
x <- read.zoo(df, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

> Error in read.zoo(df, format = "%d/%m/%Y") :    index has 6935 bad
>   entries at data rows:

I also tried and received:

```
m <- daily2monthly(x)
```

> Error in UseMethod("time<-") :    no applicable method for 'time<-'
>   applied to an object of class "zoo"

All the other functions are working in the package including:

```
nyears <- yip(from=start(x), to=end(x), out.type="nmbr" ) )

smry(x)

hydroplot(x, var.type="Precipitation", main="at Lake Caroline",
          pfreq = "dm", from="2001-01-01")
```

So, I do not really understand why I am hitting the wall here with `daily2monthy()`

I could really use your help! Thanks so much!

Comment: What happens if you just run `m <- daily2monthly(x)`

Comment: Error in UseMethod("time<-") : 
  no applicable method for 'time<-' applied to an object of class "zoo"

Comment: It's running for me. It requires xts package as well. did you get any warning while loading those packages?

Comment: I did also call that, and it should load with hydroTSM too. It is something with my local install tho - see Answer below. 

Any idea? Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Package names are case sensitive and the name is `hydroTSM`, not `HydroTSM`.  (2) Also it loads zoo so you don't need an extra library statement for that and (3) `read.zoo` can read the file directly and convert the Date column at the same time:  `library(hydroTSM); 
x <- read.zoo("Rainfall2", format = "%m/%d/%y", header = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround. There are a couple of issues here. One pertaining to my formatting the dates in zoo, and the other having something to do with the library that `daily2monthly()` resides in.

First thing I did was fix the zoo formatting issue.

**FROM:** `x <- read.zoo(df, format = "%Y-%m-%d")`

**TO:** `x <- read.zoo(df, format = "%d/%m/%Y")`

That solved the errors with zoo. Then I noticed the library issue when calling the function in the console:

[image]

So, I looked up the [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hydroTSM/versions/0.5-1/topics/(sub)daily2monthly) and learned you can call `subdaily2monthly()`, which I tried and it worked. Still not exactly sure the cause, but I think it has something to do with the clashing of libraries assuming `daily2monthly()` should be part of the hydroTSM group when calling the function from the console.

**NEW CODE:**

```
df <- read.table("Rainfall2" , header = TRUE, sep="\t")
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date , format = "%m/%d/%y")
x <- zoo(df[, -1], df[, 1])
x <- read.zoo(df, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
m <- subdaily2monthly(x, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

and so on...